# Execution order of ExceptionMapper

Tags: java, jax-rs

I have an exception mapper as following

```
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response.Status;
import javax.ws.rs.ext.ExceptionMapper;
import javax.ws.rs.ext.Provider;

@Provider
public class NotFoundMapper implements ExceptionMapper<NotFoundException> {

    private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass());
    private final MapperResponseBuilder responseBuilder = new MapperResponseBuilder();

    @Override
    public Response toResponse(NotFoundException ex) {
        log.warn("NotFoundException : " + ex.getMessage(), ex);
        return responseBuilder.buildErrorResponse(ex.getMessage(), Status.BAD_REQUEST);
    }
}
```

So the NotFoundException is a RuntimeException. I would like to have 3 exception mappers, which maps

1. NotFoundException with higer priority
2. RuntimeException with next priority
3. finally Exception

Is there any way to priorities those ?

Comment: It already runs with that priority. The most specific one is hit. If you are wanting all three mappers to get hit, that won't happen. Only one mapper hit per request. It's a safety mechanism to avoid infinite loops.

Comment: Thank you @peeskillet, You can add this as an asnwer

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It already runs with that priority. The most specific one is hit.

From the [JAX-RS spec](https://jax-rs-spec.java.net/)

> When choosing an exception mapping provider to map an exception, an implementation MUST use the provider whose generic type is the nearest superclass of the exception.

If I am not understanding your question correctly, and instead you are wanting all three mappers to get hit, that won't happen. Only one mapper hit per request. It's a safety mechanism to avoid infinite loops.

Comment: I came to this question because Jersey seems to be sometimes using the wrong exception mapper based on the ordering in which I register them. It doesnt seem jersey (2.8.6 or 2.9.0) adheres to the spec in some weird cases?